# Databases normalization in 2NF

Tags: mysql

I'm normalizing at the moment in 2NF and I'm quite confused,  Here is what i have so far in 0 NF Colour is a multi valued attribute of Product

```
    Product = Product_ID (PK)
     Colour{Colour ID, Colour_Name}
```

Then in 1NF colour gets its own table so its

```
Colour=
+Colour_ID (PK)
+Product_ID (FK)
+Colour_Name
```

in 2NF its then changed to 2 Separate Tables

```
Colour =
+Colour_ID (PK)
+Product_ID(FK)
```

and a new table

```
Product_Colour =
+Colour_ID
+Colour_Name
```

I'm i've finished out the ERD and doing the mySQL but are they (Colour_ID) both primary keys respectively or is one a foreign key, but if one is then a foreign key do i need a primary key for that table?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get you. Does each product have exactly one color?

Comment: @TheWolf It has two colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need a `colour` table:

```
colour_id INT PRIMARY KEY
colour_name VARCHAR(255) # or other appropriate data type
```

Then, if you know that each product will always have exactly two colours, your `product` table might look like this:

```
product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
color1 INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (colour.colour_id),
color2 INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (colour.colour_id)
```

You could drop the second `NOT NULL` in case products will always have one or two colours.

The more flexible approach would be to use a third table, allowing you to add an arbitrary number of colours to each product:

```
product table:
product_id INT PRIMARY KEY

product_colors table:
product_id INT FOREIGN KEY (product.product_id)
colour_id INT FOREIGN KEY (colour.colour_id)
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, colour_id)
```

So, in this case, both id fields are foreign keys on their own while together forming the primary key so it's impossible to add the same colour to the same product twice.

(pseudo SQL syntax used)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I finally understand what I need to do now. In the case not every product has more than one colour, the more flexible approach would still apply?

Comment: The first approach works as long as you can guarantee each product ever to only have zero, one or two colours. In every other situation, you need the flexible approach. Actually, I would always suggest going with the second one as you never know what your system will be required to support in the future. Also, please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I visualize this:

```
Product = Product_ID (PK), Colour_ID (FK)
Colour =  Colour_ID (PK), Colour_Name

 ________________________    _________________________
| Product_ID | Colour_ID |  | Colour_ID | Colour_Name | 
--------------------------  ---------------------------
|____________|___________|  |___________|_____________|
```

Comment: This would be valid only if each product had at most one color.